# Box.com JAVA SDK classpath? Have you ever used Box.com JAVA api?

Tags: java, import, classpath, box-api

I want to use the box.com API. I downloaded the files and checked some example code, which used these imports:

```
import com.box.boxjavalibv2.*;
import com.box.boxjavalibv2.dao.*;
import com.box.boxjavalibv2.exceptions.*;
import com.box.boxjavalibv2.requests.requestobjects.*;
import com.box.restclientv2.exceptions.*;
```

However, when I tried the exact same imports, Netbeans says that the package `com.box.boxjavalibv2` does not exist.

So I checked the JAR files and tried to find 'com.box.boxjavalibv2', but did not succeed.
I do not know how to fix this, advice is welcome.

Comment: Have you imported the library intro the project?

Comment: @RamonBoza Of course, I have experience using dropbox api. I know how to import JAR files.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions can be found in the [Github repo](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2), but are also pasted below

Eclipse

To build from Eclipse, simply import the project into your workspace as an existing project.

Ant

The easiest way of building with Ant is by running ant from the BoxJavaLibraryV2 directory. This will output a JAR to dist/debug/BoxJavaLibraryV2.jar. You can see a full list of additional targets by running ant -p.

$ ant -p

Main targets:

clean    Removes any built files.
debug    Performs a debug build.
release  Performs a release build.
test     Performs a debug build and then runs tests.
Default target: debug
Gradle (Experimental)

There is also experimental support for Gradle, allowing you to use the SDK with Android Studio. You must have Gradle 1.6 installed.

Running gradle build will build the SDK and run its tests. A JAR will be placed in build/libs/BoxJavaLibraryV2-1.0.jar. Alternatively, you can run gradle install which will install the SDK to you local Maven repository. It can then be referenced from other projects with the dependency string com.box.boxjavalibv2:BoxJavaLibraryV2:1.0.

Note for Android users: You might get a warning that says "WARNING: Dependency commons-logging :commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for the default configuration as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android." This is expected and shouldn't affect your build.